# TFS - linking issues/bugs from source code

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

Is it possible to link from Visual Studio source files to a particular TFS issues, something like the following

```
void main() {  // Issue1
}              // Issue2
```

.. where clicking on Issue1/2 auto opens associated TFS issue.

Maybe some extension exists to help on this?

Binding issue with particular source code block[s] comments will be helpful too.

Comment: What about inserting a url to the TFS web-access workitem url? Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466441/how-to-map-a-tfs-item-url-to-something-viewable

Comment: Nice. This will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wholetomato.com/products/sourcelinks/default2.asp looks like what you want and appears to support multiple bug trackers through api/plugins, however no TFS plug exists currently.

Comment: good link anyway, and there is a chance the devs will add tfs support, esp. with the coming free/affordable versions of tfs..

Comment: @JohnSaunders because the developers expect people to extend themselves it to support their own bug trackers.  It looks like it would take less than 30 minutes to add support tfs web-access with it, but a bit longer to support an in visual studio experience.